# Show that $\forall A,B\in P(S), f(A\cup B)=f(A)+f(B)−f(A\cap B)$

Tags: discrete-mathematics

> Let $S$ be a set and let $f$ be a function from $\mathcal P(S)$ to $\mathbb R$
>    such that for all $A,B\in\mathcal P(S)$ with $A\cap B=\emptyset$, $$f(A\cup B)=f(A)+f(B)$$
>   Show that for all $A,B\in\mathcal P(S)$,
>   $$f(A\cup B)=f(A)+f(B)−f(A\cap B)$$

I have tried to do this but I didn't quite understand.

Answer (score 1):

Hint: If we say $X=Y\uplus Z$ to mean that $X=Y\cup Z$ and $Y\cap Z=\emptyset$, then $$A\cup B=A\uplus(B\setminus A)\\B=(B\setminus A)\uplus(A\cap B)$$

Comment: Excellent use of notation! +1

Comment: @AndrewOstergaard LOL.  I feel like there was some sort of notation similar to this for supplementary subspaces of a vector space that my professor really hated, but this was the closest thing I could find.